# "npx react-native init client" fails on Android while executing. Could not find tools.jar. React Native 0.62.2

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, npm

System: Windows 10 
NodeJS: v13.8.0 
React Native: 0.62.2 
React: "16.11.0"

It also happens with typescript template

After I run `npm run android`, I have these logs:

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" 
flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
14 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 8 up-to-date

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: 
https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with -- 
verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


ERROR: Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251 contains a valid JDK installation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. 
 Problem was in

```
ERROR: Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251 contains a valid JDK installation
```

I just copied `tools.jar` from `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib` into `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251\lib`